# How do I group by multiple columns and count in PySpark?

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How do I do this analysis in `PySpark?` 
Not sure how to this with `groupBy`:

**Input**

| ID | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 |
| AAA | 2 |
| BBB | 3 |
| BBB | 2 |
| AAA | 2 |
| BBB | 2 |

**Output**

| ID | Rating | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 | 1 |
| AAA | 2 | 2 |
| BBB | 2 | 2 |
| BBB | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by both ID and Rating columns:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('ID', 'Rating').agg(F.count('*').alias('Frequency')).orderBy('ID', 'Rating')
```