# Transforming data using agg/count on pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, data-analysis

I have a data that looks like this

```
gcol1 | gcol2 | ccol1 
a     | 1     | apple
b     | 1     | orange
a     | 2     | null
b     | 1     | orange
b     | 1     | orange
```

and would like to group by on gcols and get a count of distinct values on `ccol1` and get the count of that as an output. So the output would be

```
a | 1 | apple  | 1
a | 2 | null   | 1
b | 1 | orange | 3
```

It looks like I may need to do some pivot, but lost on how to achieve this. Can anyone help using ideally pyspark but I can also convert to Pandas if necessary. I'm not just trying to print out, but actually save the result as another data structure, like pyspark dataframe. And as value_counts silently drop nulls and nans, I need a way to not drop them.

Comment: Just use `value_counts`

Comment: @mozway value_counts drops nulls and nans, also I'm not just trying to print out but save it as a new dataframe (pyspark df would be ideal).

Comment: @mozway removing pandas from the tag as the conversion from the pyspark df to pandas is taking way too long

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66024200/how-do-i-group-by-multiple-columns-and-count-in-pyspark

Comment: On Pandas `value_counts` has an optional `dropna=False` (which should be the default IMHO).  May help you if PySpark has the same.